# Reverse Nested Tree with Multiple Top Level Parents & Index

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested

i have the following data structure

```html
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Top Level Topic 1',
    parentTopic: undefined
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Some topic internally',
    parentTopic: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 2
  },
  { id: 4, name: 'Just another topic', parentTopic: 2 },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 1
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 5
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 5
  },
  { id: 8, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 1 },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 8
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 9
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: 'Another topic',
    parentTopic: 10
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Another Top Level Topic',
    parentTopic: undefined
  },
  { id: 13, name: 'Another Important Topic', parentTopic: 12 }]
```

I am trying to convert & construct it in the following manner

```html
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Top Level Topic 1',
    parentTopic: undefined,
    index: 1,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Some topic internally',
        parentTopic: 1,
        index: 1.1,
        children: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Another topic',
            parentTopic: 2,
            index: 1.1.1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Just another topic',
            parentTopic: 2,
            index: 1.1.2,
            children: []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Another topic',
        parentTopic: 1,
        index: 1.2,
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'Another topic',
            parentTopic: 5,
            index: 1.2.1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'Another topic',
            parentTopic: 5,
            index: 1.2.2,
            children: []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Another topic',
        parentTopic: 1,
        index: 1.3,
        children: [
            {
              id: 9,
              name: 'Another topic',
              parentTopic: 8,
              index: 1.3.1,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 10,
                  name: 'Another topic',
                  parentTopic: 9,
                  index: 1.3.1.1,
                  children: []
                },
              ]
            },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Another Top Level Topic',
    parentTopic: undefined,
    index: 2
    children: [
      {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Another Important Topic',
        parentTopic: 12,
        index: 2.1,
        children: []
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

My challenge is that I am not sure how to recursively perform this. Also in the output you will notice an index, which could be nice to generate as one iterates or it could just come from the db, meaning my original data structure would already have it.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this :)

Here is my code which works but at the top level its a dictionary instead of being list of dictionaries

```
    const invertHierarchy = (arr) => {
      const map = {};
      let root;
      for (const ele of arr) {
        map[ele.id] = ele;
        ele.topics = [];
      }
      for (const ele of arr) {
        if (map[ele.parentTopic] != null) map[ele.parentTopic].topics.push(ele);
        else root = ele;
      }
      return root;
    };
```

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: the code I am using is the following. what goes wrong is that at the top level i am not getting multiple objects, but rather one single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"Top Level Topic 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Some topic internally","parentTopic":1},{"id":3,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":2},{"id":4,"name":"Just another topic","parentTopic":2},{"id":5,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":1},{"id":6,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":5},{"id":7,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":5},{"id":8,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":1},{"id":9,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":8},{"id":10,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":9},{"id":11,"name":"Another topic","parentTopic":10},{"id":12,"name":"Another Top Level Topic"},{"id":13,"name":"Another Important Topic","parentTopic":12}];

const getPrefix = (prefix, i) => prefix ? `${prefix}.${i+1}` : `${i+1}`

const f = (arr, parentTopic, prefix) =>
  arr.filter(e=>e.parentTopic===parentTopic).map((e,i)=>({
    ...e,
    index: getPrefix(prefix,i),
    children: f(arr, e.id, getPrefix(prefix,i))
}))

console.log(f(data))
```

Comment: I use similar techniques all the time, but we should note that it's `O(n^2)` because of the `filter` call for every node, whereas one that does an initial pass to create an index to use in tree-building is `O (n)`.  For smaller-sized inputs, it probably doesn't matter at all, but there could be a big time difference at larger sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You could take another approach by storing all nodes and their parents in an object and take only the array with no parents as result.

By using a single loop, it builds the index as well on the fly.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Top Level Topic 1', parentTopic: undefined }, { id: 2, name: 'Some topic internally', parentTopic: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'Just another topic', parentTopic: 2 }, { id: 5, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 1 }, { id: 6, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 5 }, { id: 7, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 5 }, { id: 8, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 1 }, { id: 9, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 8 }, { id: 10, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 9 }, { id: 11, name: 'Another topic', parentTopic: 10 }, { id: 12, name: 'Another Top Level Topic', parentTopic: undefined }, { id: 13, name: 'Another Important Topic', parentTopic: 12 }],
    tree = function(data, root) {
        const t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] ??= {}, { ...o });
            ((t[o.parentTopic] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);
            const index = t[o.parentTopic].index || '';
            t[o.id].index = index + (index && '.') + t[o.parentTopic].children.length;
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, undefined);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```